# Xpath Selenium- How to locate a element by the sub text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Hope you´re really fine and can help me with this short question.
I´m trying to locate the following object `id=C39_W133_V136_thtmlb_button_27` but using the text that is located after an span (text = "Edit"). Please I tried different ways but didn´t work till now, any idea?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="th-bt th-bt-icontext-dis icon-font" tabindex="-1" oncontextmenu="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" id="C39_W133_V136_thtmlb_button_27">
  ::before  
  <img class="th-bt-img" src="/SAP/BC/BSP/SAP/thtmlb_styles/sap_skins/belize/images/1x1.png">  
  <span class="th-bt-span"><b class="th-bt-b">Edit</b></span>  
  <b class="th-bt-b">Edit</b>
</a>
```

Comment: I added the missing end A tag to your HTML. Please update it if it's incomplete or incorrect.

Comment: @GuillermoBastian `::before` will never be within `<...>` so I have removed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the `<a>` element which have a descended `<span>` with text as **Edit** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@id, 'thtmlb_button')][.//b[text()='Edit']]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

In order to locate an element using text contained in an element, the only option is to use XPath.

```
//a[./b[.='Edit']]
^ Start at the top of the document and find an A tag
   ^ ...that has a descendant B tag
        ^ ...that contains the text 'Edit'
```